# Desconozco cómo crear programa para elegir espacio cuadrado más grande sin obstáculos

Tags: c

Necesito un programa en C que dado unos parámetros que especifican un mapa como este (el punto es el mapa vacío, el 9 las líneas, el 0 el obstáculo que se generará y la x el símbolo para el cuadrado):
(Ya tengo el programa que procesa el texto que transforma un documento de texto y los parámetros en un array)

```
%>cat example_file
9.ox
...........................
....o......................
............o..............
...........................
....o......................
...............o...........
...........................
......o..............o.....
..o.......o................
```

encuentre el espacio más grande para colocar un cuadrado o rectángulo sin obstáculos y lo escriba.
Tendría que quedar:

```
%>./bsq example_file
.....xxxxxxx...............
....oxxxxxxx...............
.....xxxxxxxo..............
.....xxxxxxx...............
....oxxxxxxx...............
.....xxxxxxx...o...........
.....xxxxxxx...............
......o..............o.....
..o.......o................
%>
```

De momento tengo el siguiente código;

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
​
//pre: map_size = {x, y}, map_char = {symbolmap, symbolObstacle, symbolSquare}
void    spaceSearcher(int *map_size, char *map_char,  char *map)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int max;
    int per;
    int xi, xf;
    int yi, yf;
    bool began = false;
​
    j = 0;
    per = 0;
    max = 0;
​
    while (j < map_size[1])
    {
        i = 0;
        xf = map_size[0];
        yf = j;
        ++j;
        while (i < map_size[0])
        {
            if (map[i][j] == map_char[0] && !began)
            {
                xi = i;
                yi = j;
                began = true;
            }
            if (map[i][j] == map_char[0] && i < xf)
            {
                ++i;
            }
            else
            {
                xf = i;
                yf = j;
                i = 0;
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
​
```

Comment: Yo empezaría localizando los obstáculos y, a partir de los mismos, iría buscando los diferentes rectángulos que se pueden construir y que "toquen" dicho obstáculo. Para cada rectángulo calculas su área y vas registrando las coordenadas del que más área tenga

Comment: Me parece que puedes dividir el problema en varias partes. Una que es verificar si un rectángulo está libre de obstáculos, una que genere rectángulos y otra que determine cuál es más grande.